# how to change the backgroud color of the wordpress site theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this is part of my css file

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;

}
body {
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:13px;

background:url(./images/bodtbg.jpg)  left top repeat-x ;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
   .leftWrap {
float:left;
width:340px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
min-height:500px;
background:#f5f5f5;
padding:49px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

currently the body of site is white. i need to change that to sky blue or some related light shades. what should i change for that??

Answer (score 1):

```
body{ 
    background:#000 !important;
}
```

Comment: background:url(./images/bodtbg.jpg)  left top repeat-x ; remove this line

Comment: hey one more problem occurs now. if i change the image name bodtbg.jpg to othr.jpg nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
body    {    background:cyan;    }
```